Product is visible when the visibility is set as 'catalog' while quering via graphQL in magento 2
For example, a product visibility has been saved as only "catalog", but the product still visibile while searching a product at frontend. (I have checked by searching the product with graphQL query, but it still return the product data, please help to solve it)
Fronend is AEM
Backend is magento

I believe that for a configurable or bundle product, you need to set all the child product options to Catalog visibility for it to work correctly. To test this, try creating a new simple product and set its visibility to Catalog. You will see that the product is not visible on the frontend search.

@Jayashree N
Hey,
Check Product Visibility:
Ensure that the product visibility is set to 'Catalog' in the Magento admin panel. Go to Catalog > Products, edit the product, and set the Visibility attribute to Catalog.
GraphQL Query:
Use the following GraphQL query to fetch products. This query filters products that are visible in the catalog:
{
  products(
    filter: {
      visibility: {
        in: ["2", "3"]
      }
    }
  ) {
    items {
      id
      name
      sku
      visibility
    }
  }
}

In the filter, visibility uses:
2 for 'Catalog'
3 for 'Catalog, Search'
Ensure Indexes Are Updated:
Ensure that the indexes are up-to-date. You can reindex from the command line using:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Here’s an example of a complete GraphQL query that filters products based on their visibility:
{
  products(
    filter: {
      visibility: {
        in: ["2", "3"]
      }
    }
  ) {
    items {
      id
      name
      sku
      visibility
      price {
        regularPrice {
          amount {
            value
            currency
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Feel free to ask all your queries until you resolve your issue. Thank You!

Hi @Sanjay, It works fine without filters. If i add filter it returns product data

The expected result is with filters the product data should not to be return

please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/374219/visibility-settings-not-working-properly-for-a-product-in-magento-2-via-graphql

Thanks for the response, now i understood and it works fine
