Visibility settings not working properly for a product in magento 2 via graphQL
The product (SKU-K1234) setting for Visibility is Catalog, but the product still visbile while searching product via graphQL
For example
If i use a query to search a same product like below, it works correctly
{
  products(search: "K1234") {
    total_count
    items {
      name
      sku
      visibility
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
        }
      }
    }
    page_info {
      page_size
      current_page
    }
  }
}


But When i used to search a product with filters, it returns product data.Please look on following reference

Anyone help me to sort out the issue.
